# How do I allow a ruby script (program ?) to access the internet through an http proxy?

Tags: ruby, vim, blogger, http-proxy, vim-plugin

I was trying to install the [blogger plugin for vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2638) .

According to the  [instructions](https://github.com/ujihisa/blogger.vim) , after installation and configuration, I should be able to write something like this :

> > e blogger:list

and I will see the list of the blog posts I have published. However I get the following error :

`/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:inopen'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in connect'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:intimeout'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in timeout'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:inconnect'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in do_start'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:instart'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in get_response'
  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:356:inget'
  from /home/messi/.vim/autoload/metarw/blogger.rb:217:in __pagen
  from /home/messi/.vim/autoload/metarw/blogger.rb:130:inlist'
  from /home/messi/.vim/autoload/metarw/blogger.rb:329`

I am behind an HTTP proxy. So I am guessing that is why I am getting these errors. I don't want to have to  change the ruby scripts to make them work with the proxy settings.  I tried setting environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` to the correct value to get it to work, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SW does not seem to contain code for dealing with proxies. I fear you have to change `blogger.rb`.

See [ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html), you have to replace `Net::HTTP.get` by `Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_addr, proxy_port).get` and so on. Maybe it is possible to achieve this centrally by some monkey-patching.

Comment: Hi, blogger.rb also uses other ruby scripts, which I cannot be sure that are not using Net::HTTP.get themselves and which I definiely wouldn't want to change. Do you think that just changing this blogger.rb I should be able to get it to work ?

Comment: `blogger.rb` just requires libraries. These themselves should not initiate HTTP sessions. So yes, I definitely think changing `blogger.rb` is enough.

Comment: Can  I define proxy_addr and proxy_port anywhere in the file ? I defined them right after all the requrie statements outside any scope. But that seems to be giving an error.

Comment: If you want to access them from everywhere, you have to define global variables like `$proxy_addr` (and also use it that way).

Comment: yes I used global variables and was able to proceed. However, the script  still does not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587641/ruby-cant-find-the-method-capture2e-from-open3-module

Comment: @AnkurVj does your blogger script work now? I try to get in working with vim, but somehow it does not. Seems to be metarw, as blogger.rb works on the command line. Does your metarw work? Do you know how I can test it? best regards

Comment: @jerik I have long since forsaken that script. I no longer remember any details.