# Ruby can't find the method capture2e from open3 module

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use the script   [blogger.rb](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2638)  and I just can't get it work. It keeps giving me the error :

> > blogger.rb:294:in `text2html': undefined method`capture2' for Open3:Module (NoMethodError)

The script does a `require Open3` in the beginning. I don't understand where is the problem ! I have no knowledge  of Ruby. However, I can intelligently read and edit codes in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that you're using Ruby 1.8 but the script requires 1.9. The [Open3 class in 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html) has a `popen3` class method and nothing else. The [Ruby 1.9 Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html) has the `capture2` and `capture2e` class methods that you're looking for. So you need to upgrade your Ruby to 1.9 or find another script.

Comment: But there doesn't seem to be any corresponding package called rubygems1.9 ! When I install ruby gems it installs ruby1.8 and ruby1.8dev automatically

Comment: @AnkurVj: Which OS/platform/distribution? Ubuntu or some other Debian variant perhaps?

Comment: Ubuntu yeah. I found out that 1.9.1 ships with gems by default. It was just named gems1.9.1 instead of gems and so  I created a soft link and everything works.